# how to get an array from mongodb/mongodb package

Tags: php, mongodb

recently I started using MongoDB and I found this https://packagist.org/packages/mongodb/mongodb package. it seems a good one to work with. but I cant get an array when I want to find a specific data or the whole collection. it gives me object or collection of objects( depends on the find() or findMany() method) but i need a PHP array to work with it( do some loops, check some conditions or pass them into View side).

```
use MongoDB\Client;

$mongoObject = new Client();

$usersCollection = $mongoObject->selectDatabase('test')->selectCollection('users');

$users = $usersCollection->find([]);

foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo "<pre style='font-size: 20px;'>";
        var_dump($user);
        echo "</pre>";
}

die();
```

the package is recommanded by php.net himself check it out here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

Is there anybody that can help me?

Comment: I can loop through the object that findMany() method gives me but I can't get a simple array to work with!

Comment: The correct library for use with php is the [PHPLIB driver, installation and usage docs are here](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/). An overview of how different components fit in is [shown here.](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.overview.php). Your link is to the wrong place ( though you appear to mean the composer package list ), and it's not clear what you are really asking. Almost sounds like a "general tutorial", for which this is the wrong place to ask. If you have specific code you have trouble with, then share it.

Comment: sry for that link. now it is fixed and it is recommended from the community to use this package. and I learned all part of this package, I'm not asking for a general tutorial. All I ask is that how to get a simple PHP array from my collection(s) using this package?

Comment: Without your current code "it's a tutorial". There are tutorials on the link given. If you want help with "your code" then [include it in your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @NeilLunn thanx a lot for teaching how to put a good question. And I may use the mongo's extension himself not any composer package. I thought composer packages will make working with mongoDB much easier but it seems they don't.

Answer (score 0):

thanx to http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php this page, I can simply use below structure to get the data.

```
use MongoDB\Client;

$mongoObject = new Client();

$usersCollection = $mongoObject->selectDatabase('test')->selectCollection('users');

$users = $usersCollection->find([]);

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user['_id'], ': ', $user['company_name'], "<br>";
}

die();
```